# how to know the current running thread and stop it iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

One of my IBActions are currently running, when I choose another action I want to stop my previous IBActions.

I don't have any idea about how to do this.

Can any one of you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use boolean, something like a semaphore. When run IBA-2, set it to true. IBA-1 must check it in cycle, loop or timer proc, and if it's true, set it to false and return.

Answer (score 0):

IBActions (if you use them as event handlers for XIB based views) are performed in main thread, if you don't create another queue or thread explicitly. You can't stop main thread, otherwise you will stop whole app.